# Footer alignment and internal CSS

Tags: html, css, footer

I'm trying to get my `footer` to lie at the bottom of the page but it's stuck in the `body` section. I think it's the internal css that's messing everything up. Can anyone help?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OydMGV

Comment: Your HTML has _lots_ of errors. At first glance I see `div`'s within the `head` tag. No `body` tag. CSS within the content. No doctype declaration. Your document structure is completely broken - I would suggest starting with a very basic tutorial such as this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/HTML/Write_a_simple_page_in_HTML which should help you to understand the correct way to structure a HTML page

Comment: @SexyTurnip Thanks for your feedback. Codepen doesn't allow document declaration unfortunately so that's why I don't have it there. Also, when I tried to move the internal css to an external style sheet, it messed everything up. I took out the body tag to see if that's why the footer wasn't working but forgot to add it back in. Everything else, I will amend. In terms of the question, do you know why the footer won't fall to the bottom of the screen? Any help is much appreciated

Comment: You have a div and img tag in your head section.While i think inlined css is great for small pages, you still cannot get away with everything.
The styles must be in the head section, the body starts after the head section.The footer is your smallest issue here.

Comment: Hard to say until you fix the errors. Try using a [markup validator](https://validator.w3.org/)

Comment: @damianocelent I got rid of the div in my head section. I tried to put the css for the form in the external style sheet but it's not picking it up?

Comment: @SexyTurnip I ran the page through that check and a lot of errors are coming up. I'll try fix them all now!

Comment: @sexyTurnip
No worries mate, I'll fix it all for you there.Gimme 30mins or so.

Comment: Am i allowed to change that form, making it only show up on click?

Comment: @damianocelent You can change whatever you wish to make it work! Thank you so much for this!

Comment: The form will look different ,i might change the page layout slightly, though, but i promise you will be happy with the results

Comment: @damianocelent Good stuff!

Comment: have a preview:-)  http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/XmOdqO

Comment: @damianocelent (i fell asleep haha) That looks great! ! Thank you! Is it ready to go?

Comment: I will do some slight changes to that and put reasonable css for mobile in there as well, you will then be basically able to just copypaste it as is.But its gonna be Wed probably, very busy atm.

Comment: @damianocelent No problem! Take your time! Instead of clogging up this question, can you email me at klexosklexos@gmail.com instead?